# Other closed forms of $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{1}{2i+1}-\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{2i}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form, constants, euler-mascheroni-constant

It is known that
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{1}{2i+1}-\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{2i}\right)=\beta$$converges. I wonder if there are any other closed forms for this limit. At first I thought this was equivalent to $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\lfloor2x+3\rfloor}-\frac{1}{\lfloor2x+2\rfloor}dx$$but it wasn't. I thought of this by using similar reasoning to why $$\gamma=\int_1^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$$

Please don't write down anything obvious like $\beta=\beta+a-a$ for some complex number $a$.

Edit: Thanks to @Empy2's comment, $\beta=\ln2$.

Comment: $\int_0^1 1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4...dx$

Comment: @Empy2 So it's $\ln2$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct  .

Comment: Your answer is simple enough. Right?

Comment: Note that it is $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{2k + 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^{j + 1} }}{j}}  = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^{j + 1} }}{j}}  = \log 2.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{1}{2i+1}-\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{2i}=\left(\frac{1}{2}H_{k+1/2}+\ln2\right)-\frac{1}{2}H_{k}=\frac12\left(H_{k+1/2}-H_k\right)+\ln2\to\ln2 \quad \text{as }k\to\infty 
$$