# Identities of logarithms.

Tags: limits, soft-question, logarithms

[In this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4625292/other-closed-forms-of-lim-k-rightarrow-infty-left-sum-i-0k-frac12i1) I learned that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{1}{2i+1}-\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{2i}\right)=\ln2$$Which was unexpected to me but the solution is simple. I also found that $$\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{k2^k}=\ln2$$In an answer I wrote which I couldn't find the link of. So I wonder if there are any other identities of not just $\ln2$, but also other logarithms like $\ln 3$ or $\log_22$. So post any identities relating to the logarithms of specific values here! (Please don't post trivial appearances like $\ln3=\ln3$).

Edit: I am asking for identities of logarithms, which definitely are facts, am I right? Please reopen the question.

Comment: To the well intentioned downvoter, what was the reason for doing this? My question is very clear.

Comment: I don't know if it's trivial for you, but $\log 2$ appears also in the alternating harmonic series

Comment: When $0 < x< 1$    we have $f(x) = \sum_{k\ge1}\frac{x^k}{k}$   Then  $f'(x) = \sum_{k\ge1} x^{k-1}  = \sum_{j\ge0} x^j  = \frac{1}{1-x}$  so $f(x)  = C - \log(1-x) \; \; \;  \; \; \; $   Then take $x = 1/2$

Comment: @SineoftheTime It doesn't count as trivial unless you know Taylor series.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Indeed you're right

Comment: Sometimes these things  use values right at the boundary of convergence, such as showing your original problem using $g(x) = \log(1+x)$   at the value $x=1$

Comment: @SineoftheTime Please write your comment as an answer. I have given you permission >D

Comment: Define "interesting".  It seems to me that this is going to depend *far* too much on the opinions of the authors---indeed, this question reads more like an invitation to open a conversation than a question which has *an* answer.  This is not a good fit for the site.  Please refer to the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):  "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: 'What’s your favorite ______?'"

Comment: @XanderHenderson Edited :)

Comment: @XanderHenderson I have fixed the problem, please re-open the question.

Comment: Why weren't the reasons resolved? I got rid of interesting completely, so it is completely factual.

Comment: @KamalSaleh try to ask in the chat named "CURED"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguably one of the most interesting appearances of a logarithm is as an integal of a much simpler function:
$\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac1t\,dt = \ln x$, and more generally $\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac ct\,dt = \log_b x$ where $b=e^{1/c}$.

Comment: If we think about it, this really is interesting. We really take this property for granted >D +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the alternating harmonic series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} $$
and recall the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$:
$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}x^n \quad\quad\text{for all}\quad |x|\le 1 \quad\text{and}\quad x\ne-1$$
Hence you have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\log 2 $$